# NoSuchMethodError Lcom/google/gson/Gson; upon retrofit response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, nosuchmethoderror

So, I've had my app published for nearly a year without seeing this issue, and now it shows up.
Even right now, I don't have this issue with the debug version on my phone.  I don't have any issues with any emulators opened from Android Studio.  However nearly every emulator from the pre-launch reports in the Google Developer Console crashes with this NoSuchMethodError upon receiving Retrofit response.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: xxxxxxx, PID: 25090
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/google/gson/Gson;)V in class Lcom/google/gson/Gson$1; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.Gson$1' appears in /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1/base.apk)
at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Gson.java:278)
at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:217)
at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:174)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonConverterFactory.java:42)
at xxxxxxx.MtbActivity.loadJSON(MtbActivity.java:149)
at xxxxxxx.MtbActivity.onCreate(MtbActivity.java:135)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:215)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:142)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:134)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:114)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What I have tried:

1. Updated Retrofit and Gson dependencies to latest.
2. Invalidate caches and restarted

> ```
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
> ```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I don't see any issue while debugging but this error shows up in pre-launch report for almost all the devices. This is painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099757/pre-launch-report-failures-due-to-missing-methods-in-com-google-android-apps-mt)

To summarize:

The existing crawler is FUBAR.  As a workaround you can go back to the previous version of the crawler by opting out of the newly released one.

Here's how to opt-out:

Sign in to your Play Console.
Select an app.
Select Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings. In the “Pre-launch report version” section, move the Opt-out switch to the right until it turns blue.
After this, the launch reports appear correctly again.