# Gson library error with parsing

Tags: android, parsing, gson

I am developing an android app

i am using retrofit to parse JSON which uses gson library and i faced wired issue recently. My app worked smoothly before, then it broke down a few days ago. When I run my app, I got this error.

**Play store sending a prelaunch report with this errors.**

```
en java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/google/gson/Gson;)V in class Lcom/google/gson/Gson$1; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.Gson$1' appears in /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-cRm5_9c84UHHNjuetzsMZA==/base.apk)
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.texttransferbetweenmobiledesktop, PID: 19223

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>.(Lcom/google/gson/Gson;)V in class Lcom/google/gson/Gson$1; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.Gson$1' appears in /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-cRm5_9c84UHHNjuetzsMZA==/base.apk)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:135)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:186)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonConverterFactory.java:42)
    at com.texttransferbetweenmobiledesktop.network.ApiClient.getClient(ApiClient.java:19)
    at com.texttransferbetweenmobiledesktop.activity.OtherAppJava.setUpView(OtherAppJava.java:80)
    at com.texttransferbetweenmobiledesktop.activity.OtherAppJava.onCreate(OtherAppJava.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:142)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:134)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:74)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.a(Tap.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

i have tested sign APK in testLab devices and getting this error every time.

My **build.gradle** file is give below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.abc’
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true         
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false // Add this
    abortOnError false
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation   'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    implementation files('libs/jetty.jar')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
 }
```

Any quick work around for this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try clear and rebuild..

Comment: have you checked out this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566968/5293098)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError Lcom/google/gson/Gson; upon retrofit response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557749/nosuchmethoderror-lcom-google-gson-gson-upon-retrofit-response)

Comment: I had already tried but still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

can you please use this library and also use blow code in the retrofit interface  thank you

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```